# Having issues with SELECT in MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

AM working on a project in CodeIgniter and am trying to change my project database from mysql to mssql, but unfortunately all my sql code that were working quite well in mysql are starting to generate errors i don't understand.
The following method is used to verify if a user with the given TIN exists:

```
public function verify_user_tin( $user_tin )
{

    $this->usid = $user_tin;

    $this->db->select('taxpayer_id ')
        ->from('crirs_tin')
        ->where('tin', $this->usid)
        ->limit(1);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    return ( $query->num_rows() == 1 ? true : false );

}
```

I get the following error:

```
Error Number: HY000/208
Error Number: HY000/208

General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server [208] (severity 16) [SELECT TOP 1 "taxpayer_id" FROM "crirs_tin" WHERE "tin" = '1903798293-0001' ]

SELECT TOP 1 "taxpayer_id" FROM "crirs_tin" WHERE "tin" = '1903798293-0001'

Filename: models/Account_m.php
Line Number: 45
```

Why is a simple SELECT seemingly difficult in mssql? And please how do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the double quotes around your table name like

```
SELECT TOP 1 "taxpayer_id" FROM crirs_tin WHERE "tin" = '1903798293-0001'
```

(OR) though it works better use SQL Server specific syntax

```
SELECT TOP 1 [taxpayer_id] FROM crirs_tin WHERE [tin] = '1903798293-0001'
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. A realised somehow that when using `$this->db->select()` the backticks are being replaced by double quotes, i wonder why this is the case with mssql. How can i get rid of those double quotes please?